# Different objects but still goes inside if condition of response.isSuccessfull() in Retrofit 2.1.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.1.0 with Jackson to make an API call.
The remote api gives two different response one which has json object with string and one custom object. and another response cary only status and error message.like below

**required response**

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "id": 79068,
    "username": "neha.fren01@gmail.com",
    "email": "neha.fren01@gmail.com",
    "enabled": false,
    "confirmation_token": "27090745",
    "name": "ronem",
    "premium": false,
    "token": "nmdgZe5Put6kS1KC_KH5d8Tk-fZLxZ15bV5tahJwQlY",
    "phone_verified": false,
    "email_verified": false
  }
}
```

**error response**

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Unable to create userERROR: Email you entered is invalid. Provide another email.\n"
}
```

I can handle the **required response** shown above.but cannot handle the **error response**.

Here is the code how I made call

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegisteredResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegisteredResponse> call, Response<RegisteredResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {

                        EventBus.post(new Events.RegistrationResponseEvent(StaticStorage.REGISTRATION_IDENTIFIER, response.body()));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

//                        EventBus.post(new Events.ErrorEvent(StaticStorage.REGISTRATION_IDENTIFIER, response.errorBody().toString()));
                    }
                }else{
//                  I want to handle error response here.but error response is present inside response.isSuccessful() block
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegisteredResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                EventBus.post(new Events.ErrorEvent(StaticStorage.REGISTRATION_IDENTIFIER, StaticStorage.ERROR_IN_LOADING));
            }
        });
```

Even the response object is **error response** it always goes to

> response.isSuccessful()

block

I am unable to solve this issue. I lost 2 hours searching solution.
I followed [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-simple-error-handling) link aswell

Comment: you have to set response code for your error response like 404 or 500 to inform the retrofit about the response situation

Comment: What is the actual error code?, retrofit will only call onFailure if its an http error code and sometimes api's are mis-implemented resulting in "error" responses still sending a 200 status code

Comment: I want to handle the different object in else condition of response.isSuccessfull()

Comment: @masoudvali do I need to set it from android code or is done in server side ?

Comment: you should set in server side

Answer (score 0):

```
response.isSuccessful()
```

Retrofit is depend on what status code you are getting from the server. even in failure if server still sending you `200` `responseCode` then there is no way you will get it in `onError`

means your api call was successful and response came. Doesn't matter what response came from server. For that you have to manually parse response and check whether your `Json` object has `error` or `success` status.

Comment: Not technically correct, server can return 404 etc and it will not be "successful" but it is still a server response

Comment: @JoeMaher yeah realize my mistake and changed according to that.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion you have to make the response universal for all the web service. like

## Sucess

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 79068,
    "username": "neha.fren01@gmail.com",
    "email": "neha.fren01@gmail.com",
    "enabled": false,
    "confirmation_token": "27090745",
    "name": "ronem",
    "premium": false,
    "token": "nmdgZe5Put6kS1KC_KH5d8Tk-fZLxZ15bV5tahJwQlY",
    "phone_verified": false,
    "email_verified": false
  }
  "message": ""
}
```

## Error

```
{
  "status": false,
  "data":{},
  "message": "Unable to create userERROR: Email you entered is invalid. Provide another email.\n"
}
```

Please change to status boolean flag, you have to check status of the response. If it is true then response is sucessfull if false then there is some error in response.

```
response.isSuccessful()
```

instead of above you need to check the status code of the server response, if it is 200 then web service sucessfully called.